# Let for ES6 in for loop has some issues?

Tags: javascript, scope, ecmascript-6

[image]

[image]

According to the first image, we can find that i has been declared ,why we can use 'let' to declare it again?

Comment: post your code instead of the image?

Comment: Because block scopes.

Comment: In first case you don't have to declare i twice.however  you can re-assign  values. In second case i is declared in two different scopes(as let is block scoped).

Comment: Have a look at `{ let i=0; { let i=1; }}`. Now try to omit parenthesis or replace a `let` with `var`.

Comment: This Link can help you to differ let and var :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable

Comment: Thank,i have found where is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. This is something about scopes.

Var is a function-based keyword. The variable you declare with a var instruction will be available for the whole function.

Let is a block-based keyword. The variable will be available for the current scope only. (Scope are most of the time delimited with {}. )

So in your first example, you tried to define a variable with var. But it has already been declared **for the function**.

In the second example however, you can see that the variable is defined for another scope  that the one you are using (for inner scope, see the {} after the for instruction.) .